# Sample code for events management

Tags: print, events, iteration, read-char

I'd like to write a simple loop that catches and prints the incoming event while the script is running. I've tried this:

```lisp
       (let ((key 0))
         (while (= key 0)
           (setq event (read-char nil nil 0))
           (if event (print event))))
```

The script runs but no event data is printed. After `C-g` all characters pressed were printed in the buffer. What's wrong?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: This is starting to sound a bit like https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/73821

Answer (score 0):

Passing a value of 0 for the `SECONDS` arg of `read-char` means it will immediately return `nil`, always.

(And your code never changes the value of `key`, so it remains 0. So the iteration goes on forever, till you hit `C-g`. Maybe that's what you wanted, though.)

```lisp
(defun foo ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((key 0))
    (while (= key 0)
      (setq event (read-char "Char: " nil 5.0))
      (if event (print event)))))
```

Look in buffer `*Messages*` to see the chars read and printed.

`C-h f read-char` says, about `SECONDS`:

> If the optional argument `SECONDS` is non-`nil`, it should be a number
> specifying the maximum number of seconds to wait for input.  **If no
> input arrives in that time, return `nil`.**  `SECONDS` may be a
> floating-point value.

Comment: Is there a way to check if there was an event not resolved without awaiting? I'd like to create a loop that just check if a key is pressed and if not the script do other stuff.

Comment: Please don't ask new questions or evolve your question in comments. One question per post - please post another question if you have one. Thx.