# Is there a reliable way read an existing event, if any, and remove it from the queue with zero delay?

Tags: events

An answer to another question suggests that supplying a timeout of 0.0 to `read-event` (as the
optional `SECONDS` parameter) will always return `nil` immediately, and, if I'm reading the code in
Emacs' `keyboard.c` correctly, even a (very) very small non-zero timeout could return `nil` without
checking everywhere for an existing event.

Because `input-pending-p` can return false positives, calling `read-event` with a non-zero value for
`SECONDS` to try to get that (nonexistant event) could cause a delay and still return `nil`.
Practically, it seems like using a millisecond or two for `SECONDS` should be fine, but it does feel
less tidy than if `read-event` returned any available events even with a timout of 0.0.
Short of a locall Emacs build, is there a solution a particularly particular user might prefer?

The code @phils gave with his answer demonstrates this is not correct if "unread" events are
available in any of 3 queues. I've added code that suggests yet another event-queue is checked by
`input-pending-p` that is skipped by `read-event` when `SECONDS` is 0.0.

My polling loop below is more complicated than I'd like, but I wanted to record all the relative
event times. The quit key (C-g) will terminate.

The code starts calling `read-event` with a `SECONDS` value of 0.0, increasing it after 5 seconds.
It records when `input-pending-p` first returns true, and then the time and `SECONDS` value when
`read-event` first returns non-nil.

For me, pressing a key before 5 seconds is up demonstrates that `input-pending-p` can be true, but
until `SECONDS` is increased to at least a little above 0.0, `read-event` consistently returns
`nil`.

```
(let* ((input-at) (read-at) (wait-to-try 0.0) (deadline (+ (float-time) 5.0)) (past-due))
  (while 't
    (setq past-due (- (float-time) deadline))
    (when (and (not input-at) (input-pending-p)) (setq input-at past-due))
    (when (not read-at)
      (when (> past-due 0.0) (setq wait-to-try (* 0.001 past-due)))
      (when (read-event nil nil wait-to-try) (setq read-at past-due)))
    (message "past: %f  in-p: %s  in-at: %s  wait: %s  read-at %s"
      past-due (input-pending-p) input-at wait-to-try read-at)
    (redisplay)))
```

Comment: I suppose you could use `(or (read-event nil nil 0) (and (input-pending-p) (read-event nil nil 0.1)))`?  Or maybe just the `and` form.  But I guess that's what you were playing with to begin with, when discussing the possibility of false-positives incurring the full delay.  Hopefully someone with more knowledge than me will chip in.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: With the new information and test case provided in the question, it's clear that this answer is incorrect (or at least inadequate).  Clearly there are indeed additional input event queue(s) which do not get the opportunity to feed `event-read` while elisp is being actively executed, until some kind of waiting occurs.*

*Original answer follows...*

---

If the event is already existing/pending, I don't think you need to deal with timeouts at all?

```el
(let ((unread-command-events '(42)))
  (read-event))
=> 42
```

---

> An answer to another question suggests that supplying a timeout of zero to read-event (as the optional SECONDS parameter) will always return nil immediately

That's certainly not what I'm seeing in a cursory test:

```el
(let ((unread-command-events '(1))
      (unread-input-method-events '(2))
      (unread-post-input-method-events '(3)))
  (list (read-event nil nil 0)
        (read-event nil nil 0)
        (read-event nil nil 0)))

=> (3 1 2)
```

Comment: Do events normally flow to `unread-command-events` ? From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Event-Input-Misc.html) I thought this was a sort of "pushback stack", and events would only go on that list if a function read it from the standard queue, then decided it didn't want it.

Comment: Beyond the fact that there are at least three different "unread events" lists, I'm not certain of the details; but I would have expected the result to be the same regardless -- if there's an event waiting in a queue and you call `read-event` I would *expect* the waiting event to be returned in all cases.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I expect, but I don't think it's the case. I ended up rewriting what I was doing to use a timer instead and add a little dynamics into the mix anyway, but I'd still like to understand...

Comment: If you can provide an example of it working differently, that would no doubt help.

Comment: Ah! I missed your test after reading your earlier comment. Awesome! I’ll cook something up. Thanks!

Comment: Nice one.  With some extra messaging I can see that the three unread event lists I mentioned seem to remain empty while a key press within that first 5 seconds is pending, so it looks like your original understanding is correct -- such events are waiting in some other event queue which cannot be processed while other elisp is being actively executed.

Comment: I suspect `keyboard.c` is the code to read if you really want to get into the details (`input-pending-p` takes us to `get_input_pending`, at which point things immediately get low-level, and entirely outside of my area of knowledge).

Comment: Thanks - I appreciate the feedback and investigations!